# Azure Blob Storage Notification for Disconnected Remote Device

Tags: azure, network-programming, azure-blob-storage

I have several devices that upload to an Azure Blob Storage Account. Each device uploads to its own blob at about 1hz. I am only interested in live data so each device continuously overwrites its blob. Since these devices are connected to the internet over a wireless LTE network, I would like to monitor each blob and receive an email notification from Azure if any blob stops being overwritten for a few minutes. This would let me know either the connection is down or something is wrong with the device.

Azure has so many products it's a bit overwhelming. I have looked into Lifecycle Management but it has a 24hr window which is too long. I also looked into Alerts but this won't send a notification if just a single blob stops being overwritten. There is also Data Box, Event Grid, and Network Watcher but I could use guidance on a good approach to this problem. I would like to solve this problem in Azure rather than change the software on my devices.

Comment: what tye of device you are using

Comment: It is a National Instruments device which has a Linux operating system (I mostly program in LabVIEW). The only Azure related software on the device is for writing PutBlob to the azure storage account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I'm sure there is a more efficient method, but this tutorial has most of what I was looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/tutorial-log-alert

An Alert will fire if there aren't enough log counts for a specific blob within a given time-frame. Each device has its own blob and therefore must have its own Alert. It's not THAT much work to setup, but I would think there could be a more general method of deployment for multiple devices.

The conditions for the Alert are written in Kusto Query Language (KQL) so learning the ins and outs of this language might help create a more efficient solution.